# The setValue() function has Unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
fun saveImageInFirebase(){
        var currentUser =mAuth!!.currentUser
        val email:String=currentUser!!.email.toString()
        val storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        val storgaRef=storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://gameudemy.appspot.com")
        val df=SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss")
        val dataobj=Date()
        val imagePath= splitString(email) + "."+ df.format(dataobj)+ ".jpg"
        val ImageRef=storgaRef.child("images/"+imagePath )
        imageSpace.isDrawingCacheEnabled=true
        imageSpace.buildDrawingCache()

        val drawable=imageSpace.drawable as BitmapDrawable
        val bitmap=drawable.bitmap
        val baos=ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos)
        val data= baos.toByteArray()
        val uploadTask=ImageRef.putBytes(data)
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"fail to upload",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

            var DownloadURL= taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.toString()!!

            myRef.child("Users").child(currentUser.uid).child("email").setValue(currentUser.email)
            myRef.child("Users").child(currentUser.uid).child("ProfileImage").setValue(DownloadURL)
            loadTweets()
        }
    }
```

The setValue method called turns red and says Unresolved reference.
How to resolve it?

Gradle structure->

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shanu.sevenstar"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.8"
}
```

Error returned is

Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun  MutableMap<in String, in TypeVariable(V)>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: TypeVariable(V)): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline operator fun  KMutableProperty0<TypeVariable(V)>.setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: TypeVariable(V)): Unit defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun <T, V> KMutableProperty1<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(V)>.setValue(thisRef: TypeVariable(T), property: KProperty<*>, value: TypeVariable(V)): Unit defined in kotlin